Firebase FCM: How to manage Topics using REST api without using Registration Token?
As per requirement I do not have Registration Token of user and I need a way to unsubscribe Topic of particular user/subscriber.
I am new to FCM. By referring documentation related to FCM I am getting below ideas to implement the same. But I can't find a way to do that.

Is there a way to unsubscribe particular Topic of user without using Registration Token ?

Is there a way to unsubscribe Topic using other Topic of FCM?

Can I register user in FCM using any custom ID value like One signal has external_id, using that we can edit custom_data of it.


Can anyone please let me know how can I implement it?
